# Hover not working with text below image in anchor tag html

Tags: html, css

I have this code for making a nav bar. I am trying to add image buttons with text below them. The problem is that the images can be of different sizes and thus they are not centered properly in the output.

Also, the title for all images must come at same level but its not the case.

```css
ul.nav-icon {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 800px;
}
ul.nav-icon li {
  float: left;
}
ul.nav-icon a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.nav-icon a:hover {
  background: #4095A6;
}
ul.nav-icon img {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding-top: 16px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.img-box {
  width: 160px;
  height: 138px;
}
h6 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav-icon">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="img-box">
      <img src="http://imgur.com/Et4vXHk.png">
      <h6>Families</h6>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="img-box">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lubEbTP.png">
      <h6>Families</h6>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="img-box">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lubEbTP.png">
      <h6>Families</h6>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to look? Should the image scale down if it's too big to fit in your 138px? Since these are not content images, why not use them as background images instead?

Comment: I have even much smaller images that will always fit in that window. Use them in background image as in?

Comment: @caramba heading and other block elements in anchors is permitted under HTML5

Comment: ya i will keep that in mind..but again, I tried using background image, and its showing me text on top of image as well as the hover effect is not working.

Comment: For centre  image set parent div display:table-cell and inner div give vertical-align: middle & text-align:center

Comment: There is two solutions 1. add same height and width images 2. give fix width to image. like this ul.nav-icon img {width:100px;height:auto}

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to deal with your problem: https://github.com/smohadjer/sameHeight

Here's the .js file you'll need to include in your html. It's better if it's an external file. For any confusion, this file can also be found in the link above with both minified/unminified versions.

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var pluginName = 'sameHeight',
        defaults = {
            oneHeightForAll: false,
            useCSSHeight: false
        };

    //private method
    var getHeightOfTallest = function(elms) {
        var height = 0;

        $.each(elms, function() {
            var _h = $(this).outerHeight();

            if (_h > height) {
                height = _h;
            }
        });

        return height;
    };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element);
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.init();
    }

    // methods
    var methods = {
        init: function() {
            var self = this;
            self.index = 0;

            self.$elms = self.$element.children();

            self.cssProperty = self.options.useCSSHeight ? 'height' : 'min-height';

            $(window).on('resize.' + pluginName, function() {
                //remove previously set height or min-height
                self.$elms.css(self.cssProperty, '');
                initSameHeight();
            });

            //use setTimeout to make sure any code in stack is executed before
            //calculating height
            setTimeout(function() {
                initSameHeight();
            }, 0);

            function initSameHeight() {
                //if there are adjacent elements
                if (self.getRow(0).length > 1) {
                    self.setMinHeight(0);

                    if (self.options.callback) {
                        self.options.callback();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        setMinHeight: function(index){
            var self = this;
            var row = self.options.oneHeightForAll ? self.$elms : self.getRow(index);

            var height = getHeightOfTallest(row);

            $.each(row, function() {
                $(this).css(self.cssProperty, height);
            });

            if (!self.options.oneHeightForAll && self.index < self.$elms.length - 1) {
                self.setMinHeight(self.index);
            }
        },

        getRow: function(index) {
            var self = this;
            var row = [];
            var $first = self.$elms.eq(index);
            var top = $first.position().top;

            row.push($first);

            self.$elms.slice(index + 1).each(function() {
                var $elm = $(this);
                if ($elm.position().top === top) {
                    row.push($elm);
                    self.index = $elm.index();
                } else {
                    self.index = $elm.index();
                    return false;
                }
            });

            return row;
        },

        destroy: function() {
            var self = this;
            //remove event handlers
            $(window).off('resize.' + pluginName);

            //remove dom changes
            self.$elms.css(self.cssProperty, '');
            self.$element.removeData('plugin_' + pluginName);
        }
    };

    // build
    $.extend(Plugin.prototype, methods);

    // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor,
    // preventing against multiple instantiations
    $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
        this.each(function() {
            if(!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin(this, options));
            }
        });

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

After you include the above .js file, add this script to your current page:

```
 $('.img-box').sameHeight();
```

This should make all of your boxes with image/text be the same size height wise.

Next in order to make sure the text is always at a certain point within your `img-box`, add some css inline, or make a class with the css as

```
h6 {
    bottom:10px;
}
```

The amount of pixels can be anything you'd like it to be. To explain, the text will now always be 10 pixels from the bottom of the `img-box`.

Either this, or just make the images the background image for the container and set them all to predetermined sizes.

Comment: will this ensure the hover effect works collectively on the image and text? Like in my code, both image and text are included in the hover effect.

Comment: It should. This is just a solution to make sure the container "img-box" for each image/text will always be the same size height wise as well as lining up the bottom text, doing exactly what you said needs to be solved. All other CSS you have won't be affected.

Comment: If you want to ensure that all boxes stay the same size width wise, just add an extra style element to your images like this: <img src="..." style="max-width:300px">

Comment: There is two solutions
1. add same height and width images
2. give fix width to image.

like this   ul.nav-icon img {width:100px;height:auto}

Comment: Then try using upload same height/ width image and give parent div table-cell and inner vertical-middle